# Indy10, 400ms for a simple TCP/IP request and response

Tags: performance, delphi, tcp, indy10

I can't figure out why a simple request and response is taking 400 ms to complete. It only needs under 1 ms to complete on localhost (loopback). When I make a request from my virtual machine to my main development machine it takes 400 ms to complete. It should take max 40 ms. This is how much it takes max for a HTTP request, so TCP should be faster. Here is the code for client and server. I just can't see where I loose time. I can profile if you need more info.

The code is Indy 9 and 10 compatible that is why the IFDEF-s. Also the connection is already established, it takes 400 ms without the connect part, only data send and response.

```
function TIMCClient.ExecuteConnectedRequest(const Request: IMessageData): IMessageData;
var
  DataLength: Int64;
  FullDataSize: Int64;
  IDAsBytes: TIdBytes;
  IDAsString: ustring;
begin
  Result := AcquireIMCData;
  FAnswerValid := False;

  with FTCPClient{$IFNDEF Indy9}.IOHandler{$ENDIF} do
  begin
    Request.Data.Storage.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    DataLength := Length(Request.ID) * SizeOf(uchar);
    FullDataSize := DataLength + Request.Data.Storage.Size + 2 * SizeOf(Int64);

    SetLength(IDAsBytes, DataLength);
    Move(Request.ID[1], IDAsBytes[0], DataLength);

    // write data
    {$IFDEF Indy9}WriteInteger{$ELSE}Write{$ENDIF}(FullDataSize);
    {$IFDEF Indy9}WriteInteger{$ELSE}Write{$ENDIF}(DataLength);
    {$IFDEF Indy9}WriteBuffer{$ELSE}Write{$ENDIF}(IDAsBytes{$IFDEF Indy9}[0]{$ENDIF}, DataLength);
    {$IFDEF Indy9}WriteInteger{$ELSE}Write{$ENDIF}(Request.Data.Storage.Size);
    {$IFDEF Indy9}WriteStream{$ELSE}Write{$ENDIF}(Request.Data.Storage);

    // set the read timeout
    ReadTimeout := FExecuteTimeout;
    FullDataSize := ReadInt(FTCPClient);

    // read the message ID
    SetLength(IDAsBytes, 0);
    DataLength := ReadInt(FTCPClient);
    ReadBuff(FTCPClient, DataLength, IDAsBytes);

    if DataLength > 0 then
    begin
      SetLength(IDAsString, DataLength div SizeOf(uchar));
      Move(IDAsBytes[0], IDAsString[1], DataLength);
      Result.ID := IDAsString;
    end;

    // read the message data
    DataLength := ReadInt(FTCPClient);
    ReadStream(Result.Data.Storage, DataLength, False);
    Result.Data.Storage.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);

    // we were succesfull
    FAnswerValid := True;
  end;
end;
```

The server side:

```
procedure TIMCServer.OnServerExecute(AContext: TIMCContext);
var
  Request: IMessageData;
  Response: IMessageData;
  DataLength: Int64;
  FullDataSize: Int64;
  IDAsBytes: TIdBytes;
  IDAsString: ustring;
begin
  with AContext.Connection{$IFNDEF Indy9}.IOHandler{$ENDIF} do
  begin
    ReadTimeout := FExecuteTimeout;
    //read the data length of the comming response
    FullDataSize := ReadInt(AContext.Connection);

    // Acquire the data objects
    Request := AcquireIMCData;
    Response := AcquireIMCData;

    // read the message ID
    DataLength := ReadInt(AContext.Connection);
    ReadBuff(AContext.Connection, DataLength, IDAsBytes);

    if DataLength > 0 then
    begin
      SetLength(IDAsString, DataLength div SizeOf(uchar));
      Move(IDAsBytes[0], IDAsString[1], DataLength);
      Request.ID := IDAsString;
    end;

    // read the message data
    DataLength := ReadInt(AContext.Connection);
    ReadStream(Request.Data.Storage, DataLength, False);

    Request.Data.Storage.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    try
      // execute the actual request handler
      FOnExecuteRequest(Request, Response);
    finally
      // write the data stream to TCP
      Response.Data.Storage.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      DataLength := Length(Response.ID) * SizeOf(uchar);
      FullDataSize := DataLength + Response.Data.Storage.Size + 2 * SizeOf(Int64);

      // write ID as binary data
      SetLength(IDAsBytes, DataLength);
      Move(Response.ID[1], IDAsBytes[0], DataLength);

      // write data
      {$IFDEF Indy9}WriteInteger{$ELSE}Write{$ENDIF}(FullDataSize);
      {$IFDEF Indy9}WriteInteger{$ELSE}Write{$ENDIF}(DataLength);
      {$IFDEF Indy9}WriteBuffer{$ELSE}Write{$ENDIF}(IDAsBytes{$IFDEF Indy9}[0]{$ENDIF}, DataLength);
      {$IFDEF Indy9}WriteInteger{$ELSE}Write{$ENDIF}(Response.Data.Storage.Size);
      {$IFDEF Indy9}WriteStream{$ELSE}Write{$ENDIF}(Response.Data.Storage);
    end;
  end;
```

The same slow communication was reported by one of the users of my code. He also tested from a virtual machine to a physical machine.

**UPDATE:**

The following code executes in 2-3 ms between same two machines. Its Indy10, smallest possible case.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyVar: Int64;
begin
  TCPClient.Host := Edit1.Text;
  TCPClient.Port := StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
  TCPClient.Connect;
  try
    stopwatch := TStopWatch.StartNew;
    MyVar := 10;
    TCPClient.IOHandler.Write(MyVar);
    TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadInt64;
    stopwatch.Stop;
    Caption := IntToStr(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds) + ' ms';
  finally
    TCPClient.Disconnect;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  MyVar: Int64;
begin
  if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size > 0 then
  begin
    MyVar := 10;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadInt64;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(MyVar);
  end;
```

end;

Comment: You should rethink the try..finally block on server side

Comment: @Sir Rufo, I absolutely agree. That will change as it is far from good :) But for my question it is irrelevant as it does not cause the delay.

Comment: did you check the HTTP response time of 40ms with an Indy HTTP server based test app too, or a with a different HTTP server implementation?

Comment: mjn, it was part indy part synapse from one of my other app. I will check it later and report back. Will do a simple Indy only http request / response

Comment: We had really simple Indy TCP client/server interface and sending messages were slow too. By moving to Synapse we got huge performance jump. We noticed Indy speed decrease after upgrading from Delphi 2006 to Delphi 2010.

Comment: I could use Synapse or ICS, but the reason I use Indy is because it is bundled with Delphi. This is for my IMC which is inter machine communication. I choose Indy so people don't have to use third party dependency libraries. BTW with Indy9 the times are the same in BDS2006, so I don't think its that simple.

Comment: It seems you have a similar problem as described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605580/indy-write-buffering-efficient-tcp-communication

so basically you can serialize your data into one call (send one big buffer) and disable nagle (setting TCP_NODELAY). Nagle is on per default.

Comment: @mrabat, just tried that. I copied the whole data to one memory stream internally and then sent that. Still the same time. There must be some stupid thing I don't see :(

Comment: @mrabat, but thanks for the URL, it got me looking in the correct direction and helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved the problem. It was easy when you find out what to do and where the problem is. Indy simply did not sent my data straight away. I had to add

```
OpenWriteBuffer
CloseWriteBuffer
```

calls to make Indy send the data when I want it. A lot of trouble over a simple misunderstanding of internal workings. Maybe this will spare someone some time.

When the buffer is closed, the data is sent immediately!

Comment: Data is sent directly to the socket when write buffering is not active, so the only delay in that scenario would be due to Nagle.